# json array and chinese text

Tags: android, json, text, text-formatting

I am using json array and parsing text through a .txt file
I have chinese characters inside and it doesnt seem to be able to display them properly.

my txt file output:

```
{
    "guides": [
        {
        "description": "Download magazines/下载杂志",
                "image": "http://58.185.41.178/magazine_android/guide/download.png"
        },  
    {
        "description": "Delete magazines/删除杂志",
                "image": "http://58.185.41.178/magazine_android/guide/trash.png"
        },
    {
        "description": "Preview magazines",
                "image": "http://58.185.41.178/magazine_android/guide/preview.png"
        },  
    {
        "description": "Update magazine issues/更新杂志",
                "image": "http://58.185.41.178/magazine_android/guide/refresh.png"
        },
    {
        "description": "Settings/设置",
                "image": "http://58.185.41.178/magazine_android/guide/settings.png"
        },  
    {       
        "description": "Read magazine/阅读杂志",
                "image": "http://58.185.41.178/magazine_android/guide/magazine.png"
        }           
    ]
}
```

but the output will always be weird chinese text! 
e.g. http://i49.tinypic.com/211tnco.jpg

this is my json

```
class LoadGuide extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * getting All videos from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_guide, "GET", params);

            // CHECKING OF JSON RESPONSE
            Log.d("All guide: ", json.toString());

            try {
                guide = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GUIDES);
                for (int i = 0; i < guide.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = guide.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String title = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

                    guideList.add(image);
                    descriptionList.add(description);
                    System.out.println(guideList);
                    System.out.println(descriptionList);
                    }           


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        /**
         *  Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
        * */ 

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe a character encoding issue getting the data from the server? Is it still OK in the "All guide" log output?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem. You need to make sure you know the encoding of the source document, that you're reading it into memory using that encoding, that you're using the correct encoding when putting things into the list view, etc., etc. If you aren't already up on encoding, Joel Spolsky (one of the SO founders) [wrote this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) which is worth a read as a primer before you go off looking for the technical details.